# Народные названия алкоголиков

Tags: этимология

Что за слова "ханурик" и "ханыга"? Я даже не могу предположить, от какого они корня могут происходить

Comment: Я даже не знала, что это - алкоголики. Ханурик - слабак, тощий, унылый человек. Ханыга - не слышала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение "пьяница" - вторично. Изначально и ханурик, и ханыга - заморыш, доходяга.

По наиболее распространённой версии связаны со словом "хана" (конец, предел, смерть), которое обычно возводят к ивриту, в последнем (т.е. в ивритском источнике) я не до конца уверен.

По другой версии могут быть окказиональны и звукоподражательны. Вот один из вариантов возможного источника:

**ханы́к** - "плакса", череповецк. (Герасим.), хано́кать "рыдать", ха́нькать "задумываться, печалиться", арханг., шенкурск. (Подв.), колымск. (Богораз). Звукоподражательные образования, как и хны́кать; Ильинский (ИОРЯС 20, 4, 176) напрасно предполагает для этих слов чередование гласных.
(Фасмер)
Аналогично - у Елистратова.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал один юморист, ханурик - это низкорослый хан:-))